# Preview .doc document on visualforce page before downloading

Tags: document, view

I need showing preview .doc document before downloading, on visualforce page. After researching, I have seen google viewer and I have tried but I couldnt run it.

Do you have an working example code for using google viewer ?

If there is an another solution, I will happy to hear that.

For google viewer;

> apex:outputLink value="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00Pi000000R8jWi')}&embedded=true"> test /apex:outputLink>

I have used putting url address too but result is the same.

I have also tried viewerjs that is ;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/viewer.js/0.10.8/crocodoc.viewer.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/viewer.js/0.10.8/crocodoc.viewer.min.js"></script>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jquery}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="viewer" style="height: 400px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewer = Crocodoc.createViewer('.viewer', {
            url: '{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00Pi000000R8jWi')}'
        });
        viewer.load();
    </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting error that is  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://(my salesforce address)' is therefore not allowed access

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?